# Google Adsense ad code being shown in Wordpress post Excerpt

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, adsense

I am working on a friend's website: https://www.thayphaphoa.com/ which is a self hosted wordpress website.

On this site, I have pasted google adsense auto ads code, which shows ads automatically according to the page's layout.

The issue I am facing is on Home page after the grid layout there are some posts. In first post's excerpt it shows google adsense ad code, I don't know why.

Please help me find the issue.
[image]

Comment: If you fill out the excerpt, this shouldn't happen - otherwise, i would find another method of injecting your adsense codes

Comment: @Stender Fill out how?

Comment: How and where did you paste your adsense code?

Comment: In the head. That code is for new kind of ads which google has recently rolled out, which requires you to paste a single snippet. After that google's systems decide's on which places and how many ads to show to the visitor.

Comment: show us what you have in the post content from the editor. I bet I know what's going on here but want to confirm before I run my mouth.

Comment: @CarlElder I figured it out. My friend pasted ad code manually at the top of the post wasting alot of my time :p